# iOS swift 4 avplayer for YouTube External Link

Tags: swift4, avplayer

I wonder why it cannot play the External link by "avplayer"?

Only pops out an empty `AVplayerViewController` but plays nothing.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class DetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var article: Article!
    var player:AVPlayer?
    var playerItem:AVPlayerItem?

   .......
..........   
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        func playUsingAVPlayer(url: URL) {
            player = AVPlayer(url: url)
            player?.play()
        }

        switch indexPath.row {

        case 0:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath)

            cell.playVideo?.addControlEvent(.touchUpInside) {
                    let videoURL = URL(string: "http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWYak5Af5-DvboTzxQYeg7aKYA9UHYwSf")

                    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
                    let avpvv = AVPlayerViewController()
                    avpvv.player = player
                    self.present(avpvv, animated: true){
                    avpvv.player!.play()
                    }
                }
                cell.playSoundButton.addControlEvent(.touchUpInside, {           
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    guard let url = URL(string: "http://mediasys.taipei.gov.tw/tcg/service/KMStorage/355/894E598B-8A9F-BAA8-206D-8DF52A8C5763/Panda_Voice01.mp3" ) 

                    else {
                        return
                    }              
                    if let myplayer = self.player{
                        if ((myplayer.rate != 0) && (myplayer.error == nil)) {
                            myplayer.pause()
                            playUsingAVPlayer(url:url )
                        }
                    }else{
                        playUsingAVPlayer(url:url )
                    }
                })
            }
            else {   print ("error to get cell back")    }   
            return cell
  }
........
}
```

The ATS is set for all loads. If you have any idea why this is not working, please  let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`AVPlayer` isn’t capable of playing the YouTube link, which is why it fails to load. YouTube links are actually web pages with an embedded player, and not something that is readable by `AVKit` (which expects a media file or HLS stream). As the other answer pointed out, if you want to show YouTube content in a somewhat-native like way, you will need to use Google’s library (which actually just renders it in a web view). https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper Will provide information on how to use the library - but its not possible to use the stock `AVKit` classes with YouTube link.